# PHP stream/file upload and max_input_vars

Tags: php, upload, stream

When I perform stream upload from Java to PHP, I sometimes get a PHP error saying input vars exceeds the limit of `max_input_vars`.

At first, I did not realize why. Let me first explain:

The files are being uploaded with an approach similar to this:

```php
// get file data from input stream
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
$tmp = tmpfile();
filesize = stream_copy_to_stream ($putdata, $tmp);
fclose ($putdata);

// copy temp stream into destination stream
$target = fopen('myfile.dwg', "w");        
fseek($tmp, 0, SEEK_SET);
stream_copy_to_stream($tmp, $target);
fclose($target);
fclose ($tmp);
```

To get a picture why PHP would give me such a warning, I took a dump of the data being sent:

```php
file_put_contents ('input_vars.log', print_r ($_REQUEST, true));
file_put_contents ('php_input.log', file_get_contents ('php://input'));
```

Here's the funny part:
The file being uploaded is 1,8 megabytes. The resulting logs are:

- `input_vars.log` => 5 megabytes, 90,000 lines
- `php_input.log`  => 20 megabytes, 283,000 lines

Now the error message suddenly seems legit. The `php_input.log` just contains bytecode, but the `input_vars.log` is formatted as such:

```php
Array
(
    [filename] => 0018-101-001_67.dwg
    [versionId] => 11253
    [filetype] => dwg
    [‘á‹Úê-8øFj–sÙ/ghÔ÷JJÐWhvPV] => ...
    ....
)
```

The first three keys are sent via GET, and all the rest would then be the file data. If I search and count for matches of `=>`, I get 25,954 matches. I then assume that `REQUEST` holds 26,000 keys.

Now, over to my question:
I have rased the `max_input_vars` value several times, and it now holds the value of `30000`. Should I just ignore this security setting, and set it has high as possible?
My concern is that PHP removes parts from the REQUEST array if it is larger than `30000`, making the file corrupt.

Is there any security problems with setting this value too high? Is there perhaps a better way of uploading files to PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try setting **enable_post_data_reading** directive to "false" (or "Off") to prevent PHP from parsing the file body?

BTW if you are using PHP 5.3.9, you should patch the max_input_vars [vulnerability](http://thexploit.com/sec/critical-php-remote-vulnerability-introduced-in-fix-for-php-hashtable-collision-dos/).

Comment: I cannot read from the manual whether or not this value may be set via ini_set() or htaccess. Do you know the answer to this? By the way, we are using PHP 5.4.4.

Comment: Via .htaccess, as far as I remember. At http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php it is stated "Changeable - PHP_INI_PERDIR" (Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)). Should be set to "Off" to prevent parsing. Anyway, check your phpinfo() after setting it to see whether it was effective.

Comment: That actually seemed to solve the problem! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help, David!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do, is a [PUT upload](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php), you shouldn't handle it as a POST; or - at least - set the `Content-Type` HTTP header to `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 1):

In itself "php.net" ([PHP.NET - max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)), they report that there is no problem in you increase the value of this setting, however, this is a form of "use of this directive mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash collisions.".

To resolve this impasse, you can try to set the variable value at runtime, using the function below:

```
ini_set("max_input_vars", 30000);
```

I recently went through this problem and how the call was remote, not given to configure runtime, so unfortunately we had to increase the value.

Until now we had no problem, but the idea is the future, modify the code to send the data by parts and thus keep the code within the standards current configuration of the language.

Comment: We have increased the setting via htaccess for now (ini_set() is, according to the docs, illegal in this case). However, we cannot say if the limit we set are enough though.

Comment: It's complicated, you would have to configure this at runtime variable in php.ini, from JAVA, based on the number of indices that are generated by the file.

But because you can not move the file or the path and perform the treatment in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how you upload the file in Java. PHP treats ordinary POST requests as if they came from a form and tries to parse fields from them - a bad idea if the data is binary. You'd be better off emulating what HTML file upload forms do and send a "multipart post" (an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071568/multi-part-post-with-file-and-string-in-httpclient-4-1)). Then use [PHP's standard file upload handling functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) as if receiving from a form.

Comment: The file is being uploaded by buffering the contents into an output stream of `HttpUrlConnection`, and is being effectively uploaded once we call the getInputStream() method.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is valid, but you have to be aware of the fact that turning `enable_post_data_reading` off also means turning off auto-populating `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` arrays. As I am using these arrays extensively, I decided to limit `enable_post_data_reading` to a specific file dedicated to file uploads:

```
<Files "UploadFile.php">
    php_value enable_post_data_reading Off
</Files>
```

Because I am uploading using an ajax request, I can set user defined headers this way:

```
oXhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", I_sFileName);
oXhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

By doing so, you bypass the need of using `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`, because you get the information in php doing:

`$fileName = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'];`

Answer (score -1):

Try by increasing size post_max_size , upload_max_filesize and max_file_uploads in php.ini